# Jquery - Use Input Field or Select DropDown

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have a form that has one input field 'aaa' and one dropdown list 'bbb'

I'm trying to work out how to make it so the users can only use one or the other, but not both at the same time.

So if they have entered a value in the input field, the drop down is disabled, but if they select an entry from the dropdown the input field is disabled.

I've got this so far:
http://liveweave.com/HaTCBy

But it doesn't seem to work correctly with the input field. I have to double backspace to clear all results.

Any idea how to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery:

```
$('#aaa').change(function () {
    $(#bbb).attr('name', 'disabled');
        $(#bbb).hide();
             $(#aaa).show();
});
```

Then do this again but reverse the aaa & bbb id's.

This should prevent the name from being referenced by script. Then, hide the opposite id & show the current id. Just in case it was hidden for some reason.

Comment: Will that actually hide the fields ? if so I don't want to do that. Just disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to using keydown, not keyup.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
<input type="text" id="textId"/>
  <select id="selectId">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#textId').on('change',function(c){
        if($(this).val().length>0)
          $('#selectId').attr('disabled',true);
        else
          $('#selectId').attr('disabled',false);
      });
      $('#selectId').on('change',function(c){
        if($(this).val()>0)
          $('#textId').attr('disabled',true);
        else
          $('#textId').attr('disabled',false);
      });
    });
</script>
```

[working demo](http://liveweave.com/AR9vYk)